# How to exclude execution of EntityCache module for a specific page?

Tags: caching

The [Entity сache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache) module caches entities very deeply and
this module is incompatible with [CacheExclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module.
As well as *DRUPAL_NO_CACHE* option for blocks does not work for [Entity сache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache) module.

How can I forbid this module for specific page (or piece of code)?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Can you elaborate on why you need to do this?  Based on some weird experiences with this module, your actual problem may not be what you are describing.

Comment: I have website which contains One kind of page (We will call it the Front Page) for anonymous users. These pages have specifics URI's.
The remaining pages of the site are intended for authorized users.
Data on the "Front page" are updated frequently and contain complex queries against the Entity (particularly Field Collection).
How can I exclude "FrontPage" from EntityCache?